# ORDER BY for multiple slides

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have PHP query to display results from a MYSQL database. I use [Swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/#.Vu9xNOIrJjU) jquery plugin to display 9 results on each slide page *(There are 3 slides)*. Then when someone goes to next page, it shows the next 9. Here are the PHP queries I use to accomplish this.

```
$query_page_1 = mysqli_query( $connection, "SELECT * FROM tblclients  WHERE tblclients.package =  'standard' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 9");   
$query_page_2 = mysqli_query( $connection, "SELECT * FROM tblclients  WHERE tblclients.package =  'standard' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 9, 9");   
$query_page_3 = mysqli_query( $connection, "SELECT * FROM tblclients  WHERE tblclients.package =  'standard' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 18, 9");
```

My problem is, When I randomize the results on each page with the ORDER BY RAND(), it will repeat some of the same results from page 1 on to page 2.

Comment: That's what `Rand()` does.

Comment: If you want page wise randomization then you need to have another fixed ordering by `some field`.

Comment: If you need random result in every page load then you need to get all result using RAND() and pagination should be use by jQuery. OR only need pagination then remove RAND() then you didn't get duplicate record.

Comment: Is there any way to create a field in MYSQL where the value constantly changes? So then I can ORDER BY that field and it should have the effect I looking for.

Comment: Please share the `create table code` of table `tblclients`. I guess there's a primary key in your table.

Answer (score 0):

- If you have only one ordering and that is `ORDER BY RAND()` then it
  randomizes rows across the whole table data set.
- That's why you may get the same rows in different pages.
- In order to avoid this I guess you want page wise randomization.
- To accomplish this you must have your result set ordered based on
  some field (**better order by primary key of that table**) which
  ensures a general ordering (kind of static ordering or fixed
  ordering).
- Later order this result by `Rand()` to randomize these results.

---

The query might be like below:

```
SELECT
*
FROM 
(       
    SELECT 
     * 
    FROM tblclients  
    WHERE tblclients.package =  'standard' 
    ORDER BY tblclients.Primary_Key
    LIMIT 0, 9
) AS t
ORDER BY RAND()
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d4b9/2/0)

In your case :

```
$query_page_1 = mysqli_query( $connection, "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM tblclients ORDER BY tbclients.Primary_Key LIMIT 0, 9 ) t ORDER BY RAND()");   
$query_page_2 = mysqli_query( $connection, "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM tblclients ORDER BY tbclients.Primary_Key LIMIT 9, 9 ) t ORDER BY RAND()"); 
$query_page_3 = mysqli_query( $connection, "SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM tblclients ORDER BY tbclients.Primary_Key LIMIT 18, 9 ) t ORDER BY RAND()");
```

**Note:** You need to replace `tbclients.Primary_Key` by your `Primary key`.

<sub>*The same holds for the other two queries.*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, you need to provide a common seed across your page. For example:

```
$query_page_1 = mysqli_query( $connection, "SELECT * FROM tblclients  WHERE tblclients.package =  'standard' ORDER BY RAND(42) LIMIT 0, 9");   
$query_page_2 = mysqli_query( $connection, "SELECT * FROM tblclients  WHERE tblclients.package =  'standard' ORDER BY RAND(42) LIMIT 9, 9");   
$query_page_3 = mysqli_query( $connection, "SELECT * FROM tblclients  WHERE tblclients.package =  'standard' ORDER BY RAND(42) LIMIT 18, 9");
```

Where **42** is a common random seed.